# Adding an Perl Variable in .html file

Tags: perl

I have a question - I would like to add a Perl variable to my index.html page. How can I do that.
If its a Perl file it can be done by `print qq{<td>$variable</td>};`
But I am not sure that can be done inside a .html file.
I need something like  which we use inside html file in case of PHP.
I checked most of the answers in stackoverflow but everyone was saying about creating html inside perl.
Please let me know if my question can be achieved.

Comment: Asking this question indicates you do not understand how dynamic HTML is generated.  You could that only if you were running a Perl CGI script, not serving a plain HTML file.  Providing a tutorial on CGI is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Answer: No.  You cannot.  The typical way to create dynamic pages using perl is to create a template file with perl variables and then use perl to render the template (eval the variables) and then print out the html and then pass it off to the web server to deliver as your html page.

Answer (score 3):

There are many languages which "look" like they are putting variables directly in the html. However the html with the variable in it is just a template. When someone navigates to the URL that should serve that html, the server will fist take the html template, parse it and then interpolate the variables into it. So what is actually returned to the client is normal html with the variable values filled in already. You cannot expect to return html with place holder variables and expect the client to then fill in those values. what if the client side didn't have the respective language on their machine, tablet, phone etc. How would the browser know what language it was and how to fill in the values.

In short if you mean to put Perl variables in static html which you then return to the client expecting them to interpolate then the answer is no, this wouldn't work.

The only way to achieve this is to have the html first parsed and interpolated on the server side, and then return the html to the client after the variables have been substituted.

Comment: Well, not the *only* way, surely :-) I can envisage a system where client side Javacript walks the DOM looking for variables and then fires off an AJAX request for the value of that variable which it then inserts into the page at the right place. It's not a particularly sensible idea, but it's possible!

Comment: Yes but in that case its not a perl variable its just a string which javascript would then send in an ajax call. The string might look like a Perl variable but it wouldnt be, it would just be a plain string

Comment: @DaveCross I think your idea needs more jQuery! ;)